# Why isn't my <a onclick="openOverviewDiv(this)" href="javascript:void(0);"> <div>...</div></a> running?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to create a div where if I click it, it will show an inner div and upon clicking it again it will be hidden.

So I added the function and the a href around the div and it doesn't run at all just shows *javascript:void(0)* upon click at bottom-left corner.

```
<a onclick="openOverviewDiv(this)" href="javascript:void(0);">
```

if I remove the " at the end of href it will run. It a syntax error(noticed cause i left the " out on accident when i ran on local server) and then I added the " back and it stop running.

```
<a onclick="openOverviewDiv(this)" href="javascript:void(0);>
```

I've tried in the snippet and the same thing occurred. How do I fix this?

**Update -- To Clarify:**
I am trying pass this.anchorElement upon clicking the anchor tag as shown above into the function openOverviewDiv(this).

```
onclick="openOverviewDiv(this)"
```

in which it then use jQuery to make the hidden children element of the anchor tag, which is a div with the class of "innerProjectDiv" and make it from display: none; to display:block;

```
jQuery(anchor).children("div.innerProjectDiv").show();
```

This should works for the anchor clicked and not for the rest of the other anchors' children. If i clicked the anchor with a project div called placeholder1, it should show me the hidden "div.innerProjectDiv" element and not other divs(ie. placeholder2).

If you copied the snippet, it doesn't run upon clicked and as stated if you remove the ", it will run.

```js
function openOverviewDiv(anchor) {
  jQuery(anchor).children("div.innerProjectDiv").show();
  jQuery(anchor).children("i.fa").html("&#xf106;");
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #020224;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  grid-template-areas: "nav" "content" "contentTwo" "footer"
}

.section {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}


/* NAV CONTENT */

.nav {
  grid-area: nav;
  position: sticky;
  background-color: transparent;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 5vh;
}

.nav a:link,
.nav a:visited {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav a:hover {
  color: cyan;
}

.navLeft {
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: left;
}

.navRight {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: right;
}

.navRight a {
  padding-left: 10px;
}


/* CONTENT */

.homePG {
  grid-area: content;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 7vw;
  padding: 10px 30px;
}

.homePG img {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

.homePG h1 {
  font-size: 1em;
}

.homePG p {
  font-size: 0.5em;
}

.contentTwo {
  grid-area: contentTwo;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 7vw;
  padding: 10px 30px;
}

.sidebar2 {
  grid-area: sidebar2;
}


/* IN-PROJECTS CONTENTS */

.projectDivs {
  font-size: 9vw;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 78vw;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.projectDivs i {
  text-align: right;
}

.innerProjectDiv {
  display: none;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 0.5em;
  width: 78vw;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.innerProjectDiv h1 {
  font-size: 0.5em;
}


/* FOOTER  */

.footer {
  background-color: #03032b;
  grid-area: footer;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 15px;
  height: 3vh;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .projectDivs {
    font-size: 8vw;
  }
  .homePG {
    padding-top: 20%;
  }
  .homePG img {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
  }
  .footer {
    grid
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
  .homePG img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <title>Brandon | Projects</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body class="container">
  <section class="section nav">
    <nav class="navLeft">
      <a href="#" class="navTitle">Brandon</a>
    </nav>
    <nav class="navRight">
      <a href="../about.php">ABOUT</a>
      <a href="../projects/#">PROJECTS</a>
      <a href="../contact.php">CONTACT</a>
    </nav>

  </section>

  <section class="section homePG project">
    <h1>Projects</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
    </p>

    <a onclick="openOverviewDiv(this)" href="javascript:void(0);">
      <div class=" projectDivs ">
        PlaceHolder1
        <i id="icon " class="fa ">&#xf107;</i>
        <div class="innerProjectDiv ">
          <h1>Overview:</h1>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ac ut consequat semper viverra nam libero justo laoreet sit. Bibendum enim facilisis gravida neque convallis a cras semper. Massa
          vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis vel. Vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque habitant morbi tristique.
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a onclick="openOverviewDiv(this) " href="javascript:void(0); ">
      <div class="projectDivs ">
        placeholder2
        <i id="icon " class="fa ">&#xf107;</i>
        <div class="innerProjectDiv ">
          <h1>Overview:</h1>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ullamcorper morbi tincidunt ornare massa. Ut venenatis tellus in metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet.
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a onclick="openOverviewDiv(this) " href="javascript:void(0); ">
      <div class="projectDivs ">
        Placeholder3
        <i id="icon " class="fa ">&#xf107;</i>
        <div class="innerProjectDiv ">
          <h1>Overview:</h1>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ac ut consequat semper viverra nam libero justo laoreet sit. Bibendum enim facilisis gravida neque convallis a cras semper. Massa
          vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis vel. Vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque habitant morbi tristique.
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a onclick="openOverviewDiv(this) " href="javascript:void(0); ">
      <div class="projectDivs ">
        Placeholder4
        <i id="icon " class="fa ">&#xf107;</i>
        <div class="innerProjectDiv ">
          <h1>Overview:</h1>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ullamcorper morbi tincidunt ornare massa. Ut venenatis tellus in metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet.
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a onclick="openOverviewDiv(this) " href="javascript:void(0); ">
      <div class="projectDivs ">
        Placeholder
        <i id="icon " class="fa ">&#xf107;</i>
        <div class="innerProjectDiv ">
          <h1>Overview:</h1>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ullamcorper morbi tincidunt ornare massa. Ut venenatis tellus in metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet.
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a onclick="openOverviewDiv(this) " href="javascript:void(0); ">
      <div class="projectDivs ">
        Placeholder
        <i id="icon " class="fa ">&#xf107;</i>
        <div class="innerProjectDiv ">
          <h1>Overview:</h1>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ac ut consequat semper viverra nam libero justo laoreet sit. Bibendum enim facilisis gravida neque convallis a cras semper. Massa
          vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis vel. Vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque habitant morbi tristique.
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a onclick="openOverviewDiv(this) " href="javascript:void(0); ">
      <div class="projectDivs ">
        Placeholder
        <i id="icon " class="fa ">&#xf107;</i>
        <div class="innerProjectDiv ">
          <h1>Overview:</h1>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ac ut consequat semper viverra nam libero justo laoreet sit. Bibendum enim facilisis gravida neque convallis a cras semper. Massa
          vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis vel. Vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque habitant morbi tristique.
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <p>

    </p>
  </section>
  <section class="section contentTwo ">
    <p>

    </p>
  </section>
  <section class="section footer ">
    Footer
  </section>

  <script src="function.js "></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js "></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: why did someone downvoted? If you copied the snippet and removed the " it is shown it runs with syntax error and <a onclick="openOverviewDiv(this)" href="javascript:void(0);"> isn't running. Can someone help me fix this or tell me what I am doing wrong to cause the issue.

Comment: That is pretty weird. Can you do this instead? `jQuery("div.innerProjectDiv").show();`. You will have to deal with the other sections opening (use the hide() function), but I think this is a better starting point. You might have to explain a little more what you're going for.

Comment: I was trying to pass in the clicked anchor tag that being used into the function openOverviewDiv(), so it can look for the children with "div.innerProjectDiv", so I can .show and .hide based off an if else i plan on adding later. I only want the clicked anchor's children with div.innerProjectDiv to be shown and not the rest of the other anchors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `show` is not working as expected for you is because you've hidden the div using css but trying to call jQuery show which works on `hidden` attribute.

Here's refined version which should work for you. Note I've removed jQuery from code as I don't prefer it, but you're free to use jQuery functions instead -

```js
function openOverviewDiv(anchor) {
  anchor.querySelector('div.innerProjectDiv').removeAttribute('hidden');
  
  anchor.querySelector('i.fa').classList.remove('fa-chevron-down');
  anchor.querySelector('i.fa').classList.add('fa-chevron-up');
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #020224;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  grid-template-areas: "nav" "content" "contentTwo" "footer"
}

.section {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}


/* NAV CONTENT */

.nav {
  grid-area: nav;
  position: sticky;
  background-color: transparent;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 5vh;
}

.nav a:link,
.nav a:visited {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav a:hover {
  color: cyan;
}

.navLeft {
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: left;
}

.navRight {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: right;
}

.navRight a {
  padding-left: 10px;
}


/* CONTENT */

.homePG {
  grid-area: content;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 7vw;
  padding: 10px 30px;
}

.homePG img {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

.homePG h1 {
  font-size: 1em;
}

.homePG p {
  font-size: 0.5em;
}

.contentTwo {
  grid-area: contentTwo;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 7vw;
  padding: 10px 30px;
}

.sidebar2 {
  grid-area: sidebar2;
}


/* IN-PROJECTS CONTENTS */

.projectDivs {
  font-size: 9vw;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 78vw;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.projectDivs i {
  text-align: right;
}

.innerProjectDiv {
  /* display: none; */
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 0.5em;
  width: 78vw;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.innerProjectDiv h1 {
  font-size: 0.5em;
}


/* FOOTER  */

.footer {
  background-color: #03032b;
  grid-area: footer;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 15px;
  height: 3vh;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .projectDivs {
    font-size: 8vw;
  }
  .homePG {
    padding-top: 20%;
  }
  .homePG img {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
  }
  .footer {
    grid
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
  .homePG img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <title>Brandon | Projects</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body class="container">
  <section class="section nav">
    <nav class="navLeft">
      <a href="#" class="navTitle">Brandon</a>
    </nav>
    <nav class="navRight">
      <a href="../about.php">ABOUT</a>
      <a href="../projects/#">PROJECTS</a>
      <a href="../contact.php">CONTACT</a>
    </nav>

  </section>

  <section class="section homePG project">
    <h1>Projects</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
    </p>

    <a onclick="openOverviewDiv(this)" href="javascript:void(0);">
      <div class=" projectDivs ">
        PlaceHolder1
        <i id="icon " class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
        <div class="innerProjectDiv " hidden>
          <h1>Overview:</h1>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ac ut consequat semper viverra nam libero justo laoreet sit. Bibendum enim facilisis gravida neque convallis a cras semper. Massa
          vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis vel. Vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque habitant morbi tristique.
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a onclick="openOverviewDiv(this) " href="javascript:void(0); ">
      <div class="projectDivs ">
        placeholder2
        <i id="icon " class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
        <div class="innerProjectDiv " hidden>
          <h1>Overview:</h1>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ullamcorper morbi tincidunt ornare massa. Ut venenatis tellus in metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet.
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a onclick="openOverviewDiv(this) " href="javascript:void(0); ">
      <div class="projectDivs ">
        Placeholder3
        <i id="icon " class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
        <div class="innerProjectDiv " hidden>
          <h1>Overview:</h1>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ac ut consequat semper viverra nam libero justo laoreet sit. Bibendum enim facilisis gravida neque convallis a cras semper. Massa
          vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis vel. Vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque habitant morbi tristique.
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a onclick="openOverviewDiv(this) " href="javascript:void(0); ">
      <div class="projectDivs ">
        Placeholder4
        <i id="icon " class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
        <div class="innerProjectDiv " hidden>
          <h1>Overview:</h1>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ullamcorper morbi tincidunt ornare massa. Ut venenatis tellus in metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet.
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a onclick="openOverviewDiv(this) " href="javascript:void(0); ">
      <div class="projectDivs ">
        Placeholder
        <i id="icon " class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
        <div class="innerProjectDiv " hidden>
          <h1>Overview:</h1>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ullamcorper morbi tincidunt ornare massa. Ut venenatis tellus in metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet.
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a onclick="openOverviewDiv(this) " href="javascript:void(0); ">
      <div class="projectDivs ">
        Placeholder
        <i id="icon " class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
        <div class="innerProjectDiv " hidden>
          <h1>Overview:</h1>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ac ut consequat semper viverra nam libero justo laoreet sit. Bibendum enim facilisis gravida neque convallis a cras semper. Massa
          vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis vel. Vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque habitant morbi tristique.
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a onclick="openOverviewDiv(this) " href="javascript:void(0); ">
      <div class="projectDivs ">
        Placeholder
        <i id="icon " class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
        <div class="innerProjectDiv " hidden>
          <h1>Overview:</h1>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ac ut consequat semper viverra nam libero justo laoreet sit. Bibendum enim facilisis gravida neque convallis a cras semper. Massa
          vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis vel. Vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque habitant morbi tristique.
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <p>

    </p>
  </section>
  <section class="section contentTwo ">
    <p>

    </p>
  </section>
  <section class="section footer ">
    Footer
  </section>

  <script src="function.js "></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js "></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Note:

1. You can call `toggleAttribute` instead of `removeAttribute` if you want to open/collapse using one function.
2. Similarly you can toggle class and I've used Font Awesome classes as you're already using them

EDIT: It looks like running code snippet here doesn't work. I've JSBin which works fine - https://jsbin.com/dofejaguco/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Nice one. Snippet works for me (firefox).

Comment: Yeah, it's working for me on Chrome now. I swear it wasn't working few minutes ago

Comment: That's always the way.

Comment: When i copied over and test it on my local server, the hidden element is removed but the div aint showing, any clue why?

Comment: You've to copy HTML, CSS, and JS as I've made changes in all three sections